# views preview is different from actual view

Tags: views, theming, 8

The preview of my view looks exactly how I want it to but unfortunately is different when I go to the actual page. Anyway to fix this?

[image: What my preview looks like]

[image: What my view actually looks like]

This is using Drupal 8

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're not talking about how it looks *visually* but the data that is displayed. That's not very clear and lead to the current answer. You refer to the fact that there is only one title, right? Make sure you actually saved the view, clear caches, maybe post a screenshot of the views configuration, not just the preview.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Views UI is a part of administrative interface and uses the admin theme to render previews.

If you would use the same theme for admin and front end - you'd see the same style for your View. Although, you should be aware that not all front-end themes render administrative interface good enough - that is why there is an option to use separate themes for admin and end user interface.

To sum it up - there is nothing wrong with how your View's preview is rendered, because preview and the end result are using different themes.

Comment: It views correctly when I log out. This behaviour seems totally irrational. I am using the standard admin theme.

Comment: Berdir made a good point. Can you clarify what are you trying to fix - visual look or an issue with displayed data?